# Count tags for a specific category

Tags: categories, terms, count

So I have a simple code that gets the tags and counts them. How would I limit this code to count how many posts are tagged but only include those posts that belong to a specific category? Right now, my code counts every single post on the website.

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
'hide_empty' => true,
'orderby' => 'ID',
    ) );
foreach($terms as $t) {
echo  '<div class="btn btn-info btn-sm ml-2">' .$t->name. ' <span class="badge badge-light">' .$t->count. '</span>
</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> count how many posts are tagged but only include those posts that
> belong to a specific category

You can't do that via [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/), but you can make a `WP_Query` query and use the [`$found_posts` property](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#properties) to get the total posts.

So for example, in your `foreach`, you can use the `tag` and `cat` parameters like so — just change the `1,23` with the correct category ID(s):

```php
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'tag'            => $t->slug,
    'cat'            => '1,23', // category ID(s)
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
) );

$count = $query->found_posts; // the total posts
```

Note: I used `'fields' => 'ids'` and `'posts_per_page' => 1` because I just wanted to know the total posts, hence I don't need the full post data and I also set the posts per page to only 1.

And please check the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) for more information on the parameters and other details.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I see now that I wasn't completely clear in what my goal is. I'm trying to count how many posts are tagged with something, but only look at the posts that belong to a certain category. I use same tags across different categories, and was just thinking whether it was possible to add an argument that would limit the count to a particular category.

Comment: I hope you don't mind I changed my answer completely, and hopefully this time I got it right.. :)